# calling jquery function with anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I want to call a Jquery function with a hyperlink.

As I have it at the moment it is like this.

```
<a name='lnkViews'>" + title+ "</a>

$("a[name='lnkViews']").on("click", function (e) {
    alert("Calling function");
});
```

As it is here it is not working. How can I call the function with the Hyperlink?

Comment: the link is being generated dynamically or it's just static?

Comment: are you waiting DOM ready?

Comment: Is there already a `href` on the a-tag?

Comment: Maybe you just missed it, but in your code example, `on()` hasn't been closed.

Comment: Your current markup is having syntax error, is that actual markup?

Comment: do you have the script in a script tag?

Comment: It is being created Dynamically

Comment: FYI, I don't know who the `voting nazis` are today, but my answer 100% matches your criteria with explanation. If you need to know anything else about it, just ask and I will answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) version of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for [dynamic created element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375574/jquery-delegate-and-dynamic-content):

## WORKING EXAMPLE

```
$(document).on("click","a[name='lnkViews']", function (e) {
    alert("Calling function");
});
```

Comment: I proposed other way and collected -1 too so don't look for a reason.

Comment: I noticed that, fyi, added some links to your answer, since op selected it. wanted to make sure s/he has plenty of info to draw from on this subject since `dynamic` selection can get confusing to greenhorns

Comment: Oh and I kept the fiddle link the same, but it looks like their server has crashed again, so it's not working atm. I can't get on any of jsfiddle, or a few other Cali based sites for that matter. I think the West Coast has had another major server crash again. At this moment in time [`9:50Eastern 7/5/1980`]

Comment: Ya, same for me, just like yesterday

Comment: Ya, I actually found the issue, it's `Amazon's CloudFront` that is down again and that's where jsfiddle host its content from. CloudFront has been losing A LOT of customers lately, wonder if this has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

Either [Prevent Default Behavior](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or use the [`javascript:void(0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498492/javascriptvoid0-vs-return-false-vs-preventdefault) trick.

```
$(function() {  //  simply document onload call, just pointing out where to put code, if you didn't already know
    $(document).on('click', 'a[name=lnkViews]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

| OR |

```
<a name="lnkViews" href="javascript:void(0);">" + title+ "</a>
```

*then, in your JS*

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[name=lnkViews]', function(e) {
        /* do work */
    });
})
```

---

I noticed in your comments you said the link is created `dynamically`, then my solution will work for you based on the fact I'm using the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) version of [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). What this means, is the event is assigned to anything added to the document that matches the selector. thus the reason for the assignment the way it is:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[name=lnkViews]', function(e) {
```

Comment: How did i get upvoted twice and downvoted twice? WTH? My answer completely meets the means of the Question!?

Comment: I think it is mostly because you are using useless DOM ready handler here and btw no need to prevent default behaviour on anchor tag without href specified. Otherwise, i don't understand it too

Comment: @roasted it's not `useless`, it can be used anywhere, i simply added it for take on showing "whole code" as opposed to a partial which may be incorrectly inserted incase he had forgotten DOM load, that's still no reason for the downvotes. and FYI, you can use `$(function() {` multiple times with 0 conflict and keep you code orginized in such matter without hurting performance on 99% of today's internet and machines! I been at this since 1991, but it's ok, I must have 0 clue what I'm doing, right?

Comment: Thanks for my information but it is better to not use handler when not needed, no?! BTW, what is the purpose of prevent default behaviour here?

Comment: @roasted lol a typo, and yes it may be, but my point is, still 0 reason for a downvote, i'm just starting to get fed up with SO. Seems like every time i turn around i'm seeing more rude little vote nazi's kill legitimate questions, downvote good answers, and run off potential proggy kids. This community has definitely begun to fall on `hard times`. No where near as `friendly` as it once was

Comment: @SpYk3HH completly agree. And don't give up, most of your answers here on SO are followed by great explanation, thx for that!

Answer (score 1):

Which version of jquery do you use?

Put it into:

```
$(function()
{
   js code
});
```

You've probably omitted it, but maybe it's not the thing because it looks you're adding link dynamically.

If so, try:

```
 var link = "<a href='#' onclick='alert(\'Calling function\');'>" + title + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your a link is in the DOM when your `on('click')` code is executed.

The jQuery function `on()` will attach an event handler to all jQuery object contained in `$("a[name='lnkViews']")` but if there is no element matching `"a[name='lnkViews']"` in your DOM when `$("a[name='lnkViews']").on()` is executed no handler will be attached.

To fix this you could do :

```
var $a = $('<a name="lnkViews">' + title+ '</a>');
$a.on("click", function (e) { });

//adding $a in your DOM with element.append($a); for exemple
```

You could also wait that your page is loaded before executing `$("a[name='lnkViews']").on()` by doing this :

```
$(function() {
    $("a[name='lnkViews']").on("click", function (e) { });
});
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine. Your code should contains `});` for closing jquery function:

[Working Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkGgz/)

```
$("a[name=lnkViews]").on("click", function () {
    alert("Calling function");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can considere the following example :
[jquery sample](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="aLink">First Paragraph</a>
<script>
    $("#aLink").click(function () {
     alert("Calling function");
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```